# Error installing chromium on rpi 2 with raspbian

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I just upgraded to an rpi2 and I am trying to install chromium.

I installed raspbian with NOOBS opened the terminal and typed `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` (as was listed on all the tutorials I found. But when I try to install chromium it gives the error: 'Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation canditate'

I re-installed raspbian but I still get the same error.

Comment: What tutorial? Doing an apt-cache search doesn't produce results for chromium.

Comment: This one is the one I tried following http://elinux.org/RPi_Chromium

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial you listed is quite old.  It actually has a line in it stating:

> Note: currently Chromium only works on the older Debian Squeeze image. It is not supported uptream for Debian Wheezy. Midori is still recommended for Wheezy.

I'm assuming that you're using either Jesse or Wheezy, which means that Chromium isn't officially supported through the package repo. You should either use Midori as they suggest, or try a tutorial written for a more updated version of the OS. Like [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195).

In summary, the lines:

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser-l10n_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_all.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_all.deb chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
```

are what you're after.

**Edit:**

As our wonderful moderator, Steve, has pointed out, there is a security concern when downloading files from a random person's dropbox.

The poster states that he's simply using his dropbox as a mirror since the files have a tendency to disappear. On the forum linked (which is the official foundation forum), it has been well received, and no concerns have been raised.

Install at your own discretion.